# Union operation not working properly for PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe

```
gov.sort('M_Id').show(50)
```

which shows the result as below:

```
+--------+----------+-----+---------------+--------+
|    Name| Mobile_No| M_Id|Product_Details|Id_Proof|
+--------+----------+-----+---------------+--------+
|   Delin|7845612314|10006|           P800| 3.66E11|
|  Crasta|4567286387|10008|           P123| 7.45E11|
| Jenisha|7564120395|10012|           P960| 1.49E11|
|    Naik|6775785880|10016|           P258| 9.69E11|
|Pranav R|9886342255|10017|           P694| 8.65E11|
|   Nancy|6394785123|10017|            P45| 8.65E11|
| Princea|9985523660|10022|           P720| 3.13E11|
| Prapthi|9654130126|10023|           P246| 9.65E11|
|  Rovita|6541002390|10024|           P856|  3.2E11|
|Shamanth|9631032015|10025|           P759| 4.04E11|
| Princea|9985523660|10026|           P285| 3.13E11|
+--------+----------+-----+---------------+--------+
```

Now I am merging this dataframe to another dataframe.

```
m = master.unionByName(gov, allowMissingColumns=True)
m.sort('M_Id').show(40)
```

This shows the result.

```
+-----+---------+--------+---------------+----------+
| M_Id|     Name|Id_Proof|Product_Details| Mobile_No|
+-----+---------+--------+---------------+----------+
|10001| Anusha K| 2.65E11|           P246|9812467513|
|10002|Anusha MV| 6.95E11|           P365|6544477812|
|10003|    Arohi| 7.47E11|           P222|7745692311|
|10004|   Freeda| 2.31E11|           P457|9834475968|
|10005|   Swedel| 8.45E11|           P111|9856114752|
|10006|    Delin| 3.66E11|           P800|7845612314|
|10006|    Delin| 3.66E11|           P754|7845612314|
|10007|      Don| 3.37E11|           P881|8036497765|
|10008|   Elston| 7.45E11|           P421|9003664521|
|10008|   Crasta| 7.45E11|           P123|4567286387|
|10009|   Gretta| 2.65E11|           P574|9643002178|
|10010|  Grishma| 6.24E11|           P369|8231064952|
|10011| Jayadeva| 5.41E11|           P555|8315604967|
|10012|  Jenisha| 1.49E11|           P964|7564120395|
|10012|  Jenisha| 1.49E11|           P960|7564120395|
|10012|  Jenisha| 1.49E11|           P740|7564120395|
|10013|   Krithi| 5.32E11|           P111|9692013649|
|10014|   Malani| 9.68E11|           P123|7036149820|
|10015|   Melina| 3.11E11|           P152|6023570125|
|10016|     Naik| 9.69E11|           P258|6775785880|
|10016|   Shreya| 9.69E11|           P426|8960321475|
|10017|    Nancy| 8.65E11|            P45|6394785123|
|10017|    Nancy| 8.65E11|           P693|6394785123|
|10017| Pranav R| 8.65E11|           P694|9886342255|
|10018|  Nikitha| 9.89E11|           P968|7589641236|
|10019|   Pavana|  8.6E11|           P695|9674586315|
|10020| Pranav A| 4.59E11|           P256|9862347569|
|10021|    Delin| 5.94E11|           P456|7894567845|
|10022|  Princea| 3.13E11|           P720|9985523660|
|10022|  Princea| 3.13E11|           P285|9985523660|
|10022|  Prapthi| 9.65E11|           P246|9654130126|
|10022| Shamanth| 4.04E11|           P759|9631032015|
|10022|   Rovita|  3.2E11|           P856|6541002390|
+-----+---------+--------+---------------+----------+
```

Here, in the last 5 row the M_id column values has changed and all are same as 10022.
I am not sure where I am doing it wrong. The union operation should ideally merge the table, without updating any of its value.

This is the master record data:

```
+-----+---------+--------+---------------+----------+
| M_Id|     Name|Id_Proof|Product_Details| Mobile_No|
+-----+---------+--------+---------------+----------+
|10001| Anusha K| 2.65E11|           P246|9812467513|
|10002|Anusha MV| 6.95E11|           P365|6544477812|
|10003|    Arohi| 7.47E11|           P222|7745692311|
|10004|   Freeda| 2.31E11|           P457|9834475968|
|10005|   Swedel| 8.45E11|           P111|9856114752|
|10006|    Delin| 3.66E11|           P754|7845612314|
|10007|      Don| 3.37E11|           P881|8036497765|
|10008|   Elston| 7.45E11|           P421|9003664521|
|10009|   Gretta| 2.65E11|           P574|9643002178|
|10010|  Grishma| 6.24E11|           P369|8231064952|
|10011| Jayadeva| 5.41E11|           P555|8315604967|
|10012|  Jenisha| 1.49E11|           P740|7564120395|
|10012|  Jenisha| 1.49E11|           P964|7564120395|
|10013|   Krithi| 5.32E11|           P111|9692013649|
|10014|   Malani| 9.68E11|           P123|7036149820|
|10015|   Melina| 3.11E11|           P152|6023570125|
|10016|   Shreya| 9.69E11|           P426|8960321475|
|10017|    Nancy| 8.65E11|           P693|6394785123|
|10018|  Nikitha| 9.89E11|           P968|7589641236|
|10019|   Pavana|  8.6E11|           P695|9674586315|
|10020| Pranav A| 4.59E11|           P256|9862347569|
|10021|    Delin| 5.94E11|           P456|7894567845|
+-----+---------+--------+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: what do you have in `master`?

Comment: Updated the master record in the question.

Comment: Looks like you have more data than what you're showing here. Most likely the last 5 rows with `10022` value is some where in your original dataframes. You can perform a `count` after `union` to verify the number of records

Comment: @pltc - I checked that. This is a small table. There is no rows with value 10022 in it.

Comment: in both dataframe? can you run`.show(30)` on both of them?